# How to choose the initial temperature in the Boltzmann selection method?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

Using the Boltzmann selection in genetic algorithms, the probability of visiting a point in optimization space $X_j$
is

$p(X_j)=\frac{\exp\frac{-f(X_j)}{T}}{\sum_i \exp \frac{-f(X_i)}{T}}$

my question is: how do we set the initial temperature T?